# How to get print out of a ms word file from java application

Tags: java, ms-word

Print ms word file (myfile.doc) to get printed from java application....

Answer (score 2):

[This example](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling#DocumentPrinter) from the [OpenOffice API](http://api.openoffice.org/) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache POI system ( http://poi.apache.org/ ) is explicitly designed to interface with MS documents.

Comment: Can you expand on how POI would be used to actually print a document?  My experience with POI so far has always been that interaction with the Word file format occurs at a pretty low level - not suited to printing...

Answer (score 0):

The [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) library can be used to obtain a COM interface to a Word automation container, and you can print from there (we do this quite a bit in one of our apps).  But you have to have Word installed on the machine for this to work - if you are looking for something that can work without having Word installed, you'll have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient method, but it works if you have MS Word. You can use this command to get Word print the file:

```
start /min winword <filename> /q /n /f /mFilePrint /mFileExit
```

Replace `<filename>` with the filename. It must be enclosed in double-quotation marks if it contains spaces. (e.g. `file.rtf`, `"A File.docx"`)

Here is a Java method and C++ function that takes the filename as an argument and prints the file:

## Java

```
public void printWordFile(String filename){
  System.getRuntime().exec("start /min winword \"" + filename +
    "\" /q /n /f /mFilePrint /mFileExit");
}
```

## C++

```
//Be sure to #include <string.h>    

void wordprint(char* filename){
  char* command = new char[64 + strlen(filename)];
  strcpy(command, "start /min winword \"");
  strcat(command, filename);
  strcat(command, "\" /q /n /f /mFilePrint /mFileExit");
  system(command);
  delete command;
}
```

## Explanation of switches used

`start /min` says to run the program that follows minimized. You must do this or Word will stay open after the file is opened.

`winword` tells the `start` program to run Microsoft Word.

`/q` tells Word not to display the splash screen.

`/n` says to open a new instance of Word so we don't interfere with other files the user has open.

`/f` says to open a copy of the file to prevent modification.

`/mFilePrint` tells Word to diplay its print 
dialog so the user can choose which printer they want to use and how many copies, etc.

`/mFileExit` says to close as soon as everything else is done. This will not work unless Word is minimized.

Comment: getRuntime makes syntax error.