# Is it possible to pop up print dialogue while printing a document from java?

Tags: java, printing, ms-word

I have to print a word document from java. I could just open it and print it. But the following code print it automatically. Is there any way to pop up a print dialogue to choose printer? If the user does not wish to print it, he should be possible to cancel it. Also I need to close the word after printing. Please help me.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
   Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
   File f = new File("C:\\Users\\asa\\Desktop\\resume.doc");
   desktop.open(f);
   Thread.sleep(5000);          
   desktop.print(f);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336340/how-to-print-excel-file-and-word-document-in-java

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446721/how-to-get-print-out-of-a-ms-word-file-from-java-application?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `Desktop#print(File file)` method?

Comment: Oh.. That is great!! But one problem is now the opened doc contains nothing. I got printout correctly.

Comment: You mean the printer prints an empty page?

Also, a tip:  
File f = new File("C:/Users/asa/Desktop/resume.doc");  It will be resolved to the separator used on your system (`\\\` in your case).

Comment: no. prints correctly. but on desktop, word is open. but.. no content.. I don't know how to say it. :(

Comment: Feel free to edit your question and elaborate the problem further :D

Comment: One problem fixed when I put thread.sleep(). I have edited the question with new requirement. :D Many thanks Lopina..

Answer (score 1):

Try the Java print service API.

Tutorial here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html